# Control volume with key bindings Windows 11

Tags: windows, audio

I want to be able to control volume of specific apps with just a key binding on windows 11. I did find a post suggesting to use VolumeControl on this forum from this user:
https://superuser.com/users/1668957/radj307
on this question:
[How to change the volume of different programs with your keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1298605/how-to-change-the-volume-of-different-programs-with-your-keyboard/1734653#1734653?newreg=b5ac401bbfca4088a86fdf19a65d7970)

However I am not able to run this software. I am happy to provide any additional information if this forum lets me as I do not have any rep and was blocked from commenting on the original answer. Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit:
Well I was referring to another answer suggesting to use "VolumeControl" that, to my surprise, did not launch. However I am willing to attempt to use Volume Mouse.

Comment: In your link, the [answer by Anaksunaman](https://superuser.com/a/1300055/8672) seems pretty complete. Please add to your post what you have tried and what doesn't work for you (not in comments).